# How can I remove a node at the highest level of an Angular Material Flat Tree?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, tree

I am using Angular Material Flat Trees and adding implementations to give my tree and its nodes CRUD capabilities. I have implemented everything but have one small issue.

My issue is that delete only works for nodes that have a parent. I've looked online everywhere and can't find a solution for removing nodes in flat trees that also will work for the highest level of nodes in the tree.

Here is my current removeItem function. RemoveItem is called when I click a trash icon on the UI next to the node I want to delete.

```
public removeItem(node: TodoItemFlatNode): void {

  // Get the parent node of the selected child node
  const parentNode = this.getParentNode(node);

  // Map from flat node to nested node.
  const parentFlat = this.flatNodeMap.get(parentNode);

  this._database.deleteItem(parentFlat!, node.item);
  this.treeControl.expand(node);
}
```

and the code for _database.deleteItem()

```
deleteItem(parent: TodoItemNode, name: string) {
  if (parent == null) {
    return;
  }
  if (parent.children && parent.children != []) {
    parent.children = parent.children.filter(c => c.item !== name);
    this.dataChange.next(this.data);
  }
}
```

I am so close, please help if you have any ideas.

Flat tree documentation: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview

Comment: can you give your tree structure ?

Comment: @GRD please see edit.